# Amazon EC2 Cannot access port 80 even though app is running

Tags: scala, amazon-ec2

I have my free-tier EC2 containing my Scala application. The app is running on port 8080 but I have declared redirection from port 80 to port 8080. Security group of EC2 includes inbound rules of port 8080 and 80 to all IPs. Nonetheless, I couldn't access the service with browser.

[Outputs from netstat and iptables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mvEX.png)

[Security group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGTdD.png)

Browser returns **ec2-35-157-211-142.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com refused to connect.**

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it work if you try to access those ports on `localhost` from the actual EC2 instance? That will help figure out whether it is a problem *on* the server or *outside of* the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to connect locally but not remotely, chances are that you aren't binding your server to the external interface.  To bind to all interfaces, just make host = "0.0.0.0" similar to the following:

For Spray:

```
IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(service, "0.0.0.0", port = 8080)
```

For Akka HTTP:

```
Http().bindAndHandle(route, "0.0.0.0", 8080)
```

Comment: Brilliant ! I'm lucky that i mentioned Scala app :) I was binding with "localhost" before

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your EC2 instances are located in public subnets. If that's fine, then ensure that they have public IPs assigned, otherwise they won't be accesible from the internet.

If they have public IP, then you should check that the security group has outbound rule allowing those ports for all IPs (or at least the ones you want to allow to connect). If you have inbound rule but no outbound rule your instance won't be able to serve traffic, so please define the outbound rule the same way that the inbound rule.

If that's properly set, then ensure that the network ACL allows inbound/outbound rules for the same ports (and of course: it does not deny them).

I hope this helps :).